# Getting error while using TCMUploadAssembly.exe

Tags: tridion

Can you please suggest why I am getting below error, when I am trying to upload my Assembly using TCMUploadAssembly.exe, below is the setting which I have done in my POST Build event.

```
$(ProjectDir)Dependencies\TcmUploadAssembly.exe $(ProjectDir)Dependencies\config.xml $(TargetPath) /folder:tcm:226-92873-2
```

And here is the error which I am getting:

**`Error 1 The command "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\TridionTemplating\Tridion.BuildingBlocks\Dependencies\TcmUploadAssembly.exe C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\TridionTemplating\Tridion.BuildingBlocks\Dependencies\config.xml C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\TridionTemplating\Tridion.BuildingBlocks\bin\Debug\Tridion.BuildingBlocks.dll /folder:tcm:226-92873-2" exited with code 9009.`**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved my problem and now I am able to upload my assembly to my Tridion.

The problem was in my config.xml file, I was writing my password directly, due to that it was giving below error, my previous config format was like below which was giving error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<templateAssemblyUploadConfig>
<targetURL>http://machine</targetURL>
<userName>abc\xyz</userName>
<password>cdfd</password>
<uploadPDB>false</uploadPDB>
</templateAssemblyUploadConfig>
```

To resolve this problem, I run TcmUploadAssembly.exe from my Tridion\bin\client and it generated the below config file and the changes was only in password section

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<templateAssemblyUploadConfig>
<targetURL>http://machine</targetURL>
<userName>abc\xyz</userName>
<password>cdfd</password>
<uploadPDB>false</uploadPDB>
</templateAssemblyUploadConfig>
```

This resolved my problem thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That could be anything. You could try to enter the full command in a cmd window to get more detail about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Manu - I hope that's not your real password you just posted here for the whole Internet to see!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if there are spaces in full path, then one needs quotation marks around the command. E.g.

```
"$(SolutionDir)SDLTridionUpload\TcmUploadAssembly.exe" "$(SolutionDir)SDLTridionUpload\Company.Tridion.Templating.UploadConfig.xml" "$(TargetPath)"
```

Password in the config file must be encrypted by TcmUploadAssembly. In command line prompt, enter the following command and press Enter, TcmUploadAssembly create the config file in the right way for you:

```
TCMUploadAssembly.exe Company.Tridion.Templating.UploadConfig.xml
```